# How can I use Navigator in onBackgroundMessageHandler of Firebase in killed state in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-getx, agora.io, dart-isolates

I have developed a flutter app where it has **calling feature** with **Agora** SDK. In the latest version of `firebase_messaging` package, the method **onBackgroundMessageHandler** is made a separate isolate which will have its own context and memory.

**Isolates** should be

- *Top level* methods or
- *Static methods* inside the class.

when **onBackgroundMessageHandler** is made ***top-level*** function, the method doesn't get called in ***killed state*** in **release** mode. The solution for **release mode** issue is being solved as per most of the solutions provided by the **flutter community**.

The solution is to use `@pragma` like below

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> onBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message){}
```

This `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` is used to indicate the **compiler** that this method will be used from **native code**.

Using `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` poses an issue of not able to access the **navigator** context to show the incoming call.

## Libraries used to achieve calling feature

- Agora SDK for voice calling : [agora_rtc_engine](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine)
- Flutter Incoming Call for calling notification : [flutter_incoming_call](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_incoming_call)
- GetX for navigation: [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get)

## Problems

- Adding `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` does not provide **Navigator** in **killed state** to push a new screen.
- *Not Adding* `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` does not work in the **killed state**.
- I'm using `flutter_incoming_call` for showing the **calling notification** where I'm showing "**Accept**" and "**Decline**" buttons. Tapping on "**Accept**" button somehow I'm able to navigate to Incoming call screen but the next time when I'm trying to navigate to any screen without relaunching the app, throws an error as below

```
You are trying to use contextless navigation without
a GetMaterialApp or Get.key.
If you are testing your app, you can use:
[Get.testMode = true], or if you are running your app on
a physical device or emulator, you must exchange your [MaterialApp]      
for a [GetMaterialApp].
```

I tried replacing this with global key implementation.

```
GlobalKey<NavigationState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigationState>();
```

This gives **navigorKey.currentState** as **null**.

I would need the help from Flutter community to resolve this issue of **navigating** to any screen from **killed state** in **onBackgroundMessageHandler** method of firebase.

If there are any other solutions, I'd like to hear them too. Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: Have you found a solution?